# Change error message when copy a file from a link

Tags: php

I wanna copy some doc files from a link. But, sometimes there's link that we don't have permission to access or the link that expired. For the link that we don't have permission, is there a solution?
and I wanna change the error message when it happen, the error message that I get is :

```
Warning: copy(http://www-cgi.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/Web/People/ngm/15-721/summaries/12.pdf) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in D:\AppServ\www\academicopter\functionWrapper.php on line 33
```

I've tried to change the error message with (`or die ('CANNOT COPY')`) the code below :

```
copy($Link, $savePath . basename($Link)) or die ('CANNOT COPY');
```

but, the error message still same `warning .....` how to change it? thank you :)

Comment: Did you tried to use a `try-catch` statement?

Comment: @MateiMihai This is a warning, not an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can muffle the warning using the `@` operator. Note that it would still run any custom error handler you may have configured.

```
if (false === @copy(...)) {
    // copy failed
}
```

AFAIK there's no other way to get rid of the warning unless you use cURL to copy the file instead.

**Edit**

You could also use `get_headers($url)` and look for `HTTP/x.x 403`. It's one more request and personally I would save myself the trouble :)